# How to merge variables in ue4/ue5

Tags: variables, merge, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I am overcomplicating an animation and need to merge 2 ue5 animation variables into one play animation block. (using blueprints btw). My question is, how do I do this? I've not been able to find anything relating to this topic so yeah.

Comment: UnrealEngine 5 is technically programming. And it does use c++ too. But I chose to do Anim in blueprints. So will you delete your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I am a complete idiot. You can connect 2 play animation blueprints and still play both at the start. (I noticed this because of the: "starts on: (value)" modifier of the blueprint)